# How run the Openshot AppImage?

Tags: 16.04, openshot, appimage

When I try to run the appimage it complains about missing Qt libraries (I will edit this to include the actual output later).

This doesn't make any sense - but it also means the application doesn't launch, of course.

What do I need to do to run this AppImage on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I assume that the actual output doesn't include information on which Qt libraries?

Comment: Also, from where did you install this application?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda it does. I downloaded it from the OS website. Sorry I didn't add the info yet as I was very busy this weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with the the AppImage provided by the OpenShot project on http://openshot.org/download/: It is currently broken because it only includes half of the required Qt libraries. It needs to be fixed. https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/issues/220

Normally, an AppImage contains all the libraries and other components that it needs to run which cannot be assumed to be part of the target system(s).

Comment: Thanks!

Hopefully someone can fork Openshot 2.0 and the community can maintain/develop it further. Clearly JT has abandoned the project.